# R hangs when loading packages on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: r, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance (`t2.small`) running Ubuntu 20.04 that hosts a Shiny server.  The R version is 3.6.3.  Everything has been running more or less okay for about three years.  However, as of a few days ago, R hangs when attempting to load packages.

I've verified that this behavior is not specific to Shiny: if I run R in a terminal, I can run basic commands just fine, but any `library([some package])` command causes PuTTY to freeze.  At the same time, I see a spike in CPU utilization on the CloudWatch dashboard (and a spike in EBS read operations).

This behavior started shortly after I updated a bunch of packages on the EC2 instance.

I haven't found any reports of other users facing a similar problem.

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715823/r-package-install-dplyr-on-aws-t2-micro-freezing) (and others like it) has to do with EC2 freezing when attempting to *install* a package, but that's not my problem - the recent package updates worked just fine.
- [This question](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-stalls-while-loading-packages/4097/3) was specifically a problem with RStudio; the user reported that things loaded fine in R.  My problem is with R itself.

Comment: I rebooted the EC2 instance and that fixed the problem.